# PyQT5 - QApplication was not created in the main() thread

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am getting error related to Pyqt5. Here's what I'm trying to do: I listen for a key combination from the keyboard. I am trying to open a qwidget at the mouse cursor position if it is entered. However, I am getting the following error:

> QApplication was not created in the main() thread.

Note: When the program is first opened, there should be no interface. The window should open when the condition is met.

```
from pynput import keyboard
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication,QGraphicsDropShadowEffect,QDesktopWidget
from page import Open
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    COMBS = [
        {keyboard.Key.tab, keyboard.KeyCode(char='x')},
        {keyboard.Key.tab, keyboard.KeyCode(char='X')}
    ]
    current = set()

    def run(key):
        if any([key in multi for multi in COMBS]):
            #key olayları gerçekleştiğinde bunları hafızaya alıyoruz
            current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in multi) for multi in COMBS):
            import sys
            app = QApplication(sys.argv)
            load = Open()
            load.show()
            app.exit(app.exec_())
                      
    def onRelease(key):
        if any([key in multi for multi in COMBS]):
            current.remove(key)
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            return False     

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=run, on_release=onRelease) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: The error already says it, you cannot create the QApplication outside the main thread. The pynput listener should be in the second thread, not the other way around.

Comment: You can hide windows and then open them when needed, so they can all be on the main thread